# Excel file reading in Java(Simple JSP and Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

how to read an Excel sheet in java without treating it as a database, and without using any other external api's.

Comment: There is no direct way to deal with Excel sheet in Java. You should use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API.

Comment: You can read csv's using core java , this link may help http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/17262/reading-in-a-.csv-file-and-loading-the-data-into-an-array Thanks
Abhi

Comment: Why you can't add external libraries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert **xls** file to **csv** file . Java API support csv files.
You can read csv file using standrt I/O libraries.

Comment: Which standard Java SE or EE API supports reading CSV files?

Comment: BufferedReader + StringTokenizer

Comment: these kinda methods are generally not recommended to use...

Comment: @user1143825 - in other words, the Java API does not support reading CSV files in the sense that the OP expects.  Besides, the CVS route only allows you to read the data content of the spreadsheet, the rest of the spreadsheet is discarded in the "conversion".

Comment: @user1143825  thank you for this smart response it almost did it for me,

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct way to deal with Excel sheet in Java. You should use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) Java API.

> Apache POI is a Java library for reading and writing various Microsoft file formats, especially Office related ones, based on OLE2 and OOXML, such as XLS and DOCX.

Let's see one example of reading an Excel sheet. It supports for both `xls` and `xlsx` file format.

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

private Vector importExcelSheet(String fileName)
{
    Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
    try
    {
        Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(fileName));
        Sheet sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();

        while(rowIter.hasNext())
        {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
            Iterator cellIter = row.cellIterator();
            Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();

            while(cellIter.hasNext())
            {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                cellStoreVector.addElement(cell);
            }
            cellVectorHolder.addElement(cellStoreVector);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return cellVectorHolder;
}
```

Call the above method which will return a `Vector` as follows.

```
Vector dataHolder=importExcelSheet("Excel_file.xlsx");
```

---

Note : the `Vector` used here is just for a demonstration. One should not use it, since it is obsolete in Java. Use other types of Collections available in the Java Collection framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The Java SE and EE APIs do not support the reading of Excel spreadsheets.

(Well, I suppose you could spend a few months reading the Excel specs and developing your own spreadsheet reader from scratch.  But that strikes me as waste of effort.  Just use one of the alternatives that you have rejected.)

---

Re: the approach of converting the spreadsheet to a CSV and reading that:

- This is NOT reading the spreadsheet.
- It requires an external application (e.g Excel) to do the conversion from the spreadsheet to CSV.
- It is lossy. You can only read the simple data content of the spreadsheet.  Everything else is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/index.html) for reading xls and xlsx files

You can use HSSF, XSSF, SXSSF according to your memeory constraints....

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import jxl.Cell;
    import jxl.CellType;
    import jxl.Sheet;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;

    public class ReadExcel {

   private String inputFile;

   public void setInputFile(String inputFile) {
    this.inputFile = inputFile;
        }

   public void read() throws IOException  {
    File inputWorkbook = new File(inputFile);
  Workbook w;
try {
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
// Get the first sheet
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
// Loop over first 10 column and lines
for (int j = 0; j < sheet.getColumns(); j++) {
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getRows(); i++) {
Cell cell = sheet.getCell(j, i);
CellType type = cell.getType();
if (cell.getType() == CellType.LABEL) {
System.out.println("I got a label "
                    + cell.getContents());
 }
  if (cell.getType() == CellType.NUMBER) {
System.out.println("I got a number "
                    + cell.getContents());
 }
 }
}
} catch (BiffException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
ReadExcel test = new ReadExcel();
test.setInputFile("c:/temp/lars.xls");
test.read();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can this be done without using any external library and what about `xlsx`?

Comment: i am using library.you can download it from here  http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't support the `xlsx` format. Does it support?

Comment: @Lion: This is actually XSSF technique. So it supports both xls and xlsx files ...

Comment: By the way I didn't downvote it. Please don't blame me.